# how can i decode HTML code to Android by kotlin?

Tags: android, casting, kotlin

I'm trying to decode HTML entities, currently my code is:

```
val str = name
val textView = findViewById<View>(R.id.text) as TextView
textView.text = Html.fromHtml(str, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
```

and here the error message is:

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.TextView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with the HTML handling, you're getting the exception on this line, because `findViewById` is returning `null`, and then the cast to `TextView` is failing:

```
val textView = findViewById<View>(R.id.text) as TextView
```

Why this happens exactly is hard to tell without context, but the issue is that the View with the ID `text` was not found.

- If you're in an `Activity`, make sure you're doing this after you call `setContentView`.
- If you're in a `Fragment`, make sure you're doing this after the `onCreateView` method has run.
- In either case, make sure you're actually using a layout that contains a `TextView` with the ID `@+id/text`.

---

Additionally, you're looking up the `TextView` as a `View` first and then casting it, you could do either of these instead:

```
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)
val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.text)
```